# Android 4.3 Restriction on text file size in cache directory

Tags: android

I want to create a text file in my Fragment and put it in the application cache
(../myApplication/file/sample.txt).

```
    File mediaStorageDir = getActivity().getFilesDir();
    String destinationTempVideoFilePath = mediaStorageDir.getPath();
    String encodedStringPath = destinationTempVideoFilePath + File.separator + base64FileName + ".txt";
    BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(encodedStringPath));

    File sourceVideo = new File(sourceVideoFilePath);
    InputStream inputStream = null;
    try {
        inputStream = new FileInputStream(sourceVideo.getAbsolutePath());

        byte[] buffer = new byte[102400];

        int bytesRead;
        ByteArrayOutputStream output = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        Base64OutputStream output64 = new Base64OutputStream(output, Base64.DEFAULT | Base64.NO_WRAP);

        while ((bytesRead = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            output64.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
        }

        output.close();
        output64.close();
        writer.write(output.toString());
        writer.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {       
        throw e;
    }
```

In Lollipop, this is done without any problems.

But In ***jelly bean*** (Samsung s3), only the first ***4096*** characters of the text string are placed in the file and the rest are deleted.

Is there a way I can increase this size?

Or Should I consider another place to create these temporary files?

please help me.

=======edit=====

not resolved by this change too:

```
    try {
            FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(encodedStringPath);
            byte[] array = output.toString().getBytes();
            fileOutputStream.write(array);
            fileOutputStream.close();
            File myFile = new File(encodedStringPath);
            System.out.println("my file lenght = " + myFile.length());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.getStackTrace();
        }
```

(my file lenght = 4096)

Comment: Dont use a FileWriter and a ByteArrayOutpurStream. Instead use a FileOutputStream.

Comment: @blackapps Still not resolved with FileOutputStream.

Comment: Then please show your code in a new code block.

Comment: I cannot read code in comments. Moreover i did ask you to put it in a new code block. Do you like to read code from comments? Remove that comment.

Comment: Please remove that comment.

Comment: Please put complete code in your new block. And why isnt there base64 anymore now? And ehat is that output variable? Still the same? What is it that you want?